# How to reduce web artfacts?

Tags: visual-artifacts

Got a real issue with web artifacts. I create a photoshop image with text and it's crisp, save it for web at 80% and still crisp. As soon as that image is rendered by a web browser it has a lot of artifacts. I don't notice many other sites with this problem.

The images are zoomed. The first is the jpg rendered in chrome, the second, the cleaner image rendered in wiindows photo viewer. The first one is garbage compared to the second and it notices a lot at normal magnificaton. Not sure how this can be mitigated but I would really appreciate some help.

[image: This image has the artifacts resulting from browser rendering.]

[image: This image is the jpg rendered from windows photo viewer.]

Answer (score 1):

Do not use jpg for that kind of images. Use png.

Oh, and another thing.

There is a chance you are exporting the jpg files as cmyk becouse you have a strong color change.

Confirm that your web files are exported as RGB with a correct color profile embeded. IF you export as png they will be RGB files always.

Comment: Thank You Rafael, that fixed it. Never realised there was so much difference between jpg and png. I didn't see the option for cmyk but convert to sRGB was checked when I saved as a jpg. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Just a specification: I think anything "save for web" is RGB even if it was CMYK to start with.